# What does "right his life off the field" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

From [here](https://www.si.com/nfl/2017/09/19/sua-cravens-washington-redskins-retirement-reserve-left-squad-list-mystery-morning-huddle-themmqb):

> The bumbling Washington brain trust committed another blunder, this time blindsiding a player who was trying to **right his life off the field**.

I don't recognize "right something off something" as a common phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player, perhaps a baseball player or football player, has had a rough life while "off the field", i.e. while he is not playing his sport.  He may be an alcoholic, a wife-beater, a drug addict; maybe he has been arrested several times.  If he is "trying to right his life off the field", he is trying to get his life straight; he's trying to get back on track; he's trying to pick up the pieces of his life and move on and become a better human being.  The word "right" when used as a verb means "to correct" or "to straighten out" or "to put/make right".

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.